# Monte Carlo Method, Darts in overlapping area of two circles

Tags: python

I am trying to estimate the value of pi using a monte carlo simulation. I need to use two unit circles that are a user input distance from the origin. I understand how this problem works with a single circle, I just don't understand how I am meant to use two circles. Here is what I have got so far (this is the modified code I used for a previous problem the used one circle with radius 2.

```
import random
import math
import sys

def main():
    numDarts=int(sys.argv[1])
    distance=float(sys.argv[2])
    print(montePi(numDarts,distance))

def montePi(numDarts,distance):
    if distance>=1:
        return(0)
    inCircle=0
    for I in range(numDarts):
        x=(2*(random.random()))-2
        y=random.random()
        d=math.sqrt(x**2+y**2) 
        if d<=2 and d>=-2:
            inCircle=inCircle+1
    pi=inCircle/numDarts*4
    return pi

main()
```

I need to change this code to work with 2 unit circles, but I do not understand how to use trigonometry to do this, or am I overthinking the problem? Either way help will be appreciated as I continue trying to figure this out. 
   What I do know is that I need to change the X coordinate, as well as the equation that determines "d" (d=math.sqrt(x**2+y**2)), im just not sure how.

These are my instructions-

Write a program called mcintersection.py that uses the Monte Carlo method to 
estimate the area of this shape (and prints the result). Your program should take 
two command-line parameters: distance and numDarts. The distance parameter 
specifies how far away the circles are from the origin on the x-axis. So if distance
is 0, then both circles are centered on the origin, and completely overlap. If 
distance is 0.5 then one circle is centered at (-0.5, 0) and the other at (0.5, 0). If 
distance is 1 or greater, then the circles do not overlap at all! In that last case, your
program can simply output 0. The numDarts parameter should specify the number
of random points to pick in the Monte Carlo process.

In this case, the rectangle should be 2 units tall (with the top at y = 1 and the 
bottom at y = -1). You could also safely make the rectangle 2 units wide, but this 
will generally be much bigger than necessary. Instead, you should figure out 
exactly how wide the shape is, based on the distance parameter. That way you can
use as skinny a rectangle as possible.

Comment: The question is asking you calculate the area of the overlapped circles, right? So as hinted in the question, you should figure out how wide the rectangle should be, and then what is the condition for a dart being in both of the circles.

Comment: hmmm, i think i got the rectangle part. width = 2(r-distance). is that correct? distance being the distance the center of the circle is from the origin.

Comment: Actually you can use any shape, as long as it's still covering the overlapped part. And the minimum width of such rectangle would be 2(r-distance), yes, you're correct =)
@mwjohnson: the rectangle does not need to cover the whole circles, just need to cover the overlapping area.

Comment: ok cool! now i just dont understand, from a math standpoint, how i create a condition for whether or not the dart hits, isnt it pretty complicated trigonometry?

Comment: I think this is the homework assignment for our college... lab 1 or 2 for some intro class my friend is the lead TA. We discussed on what to assign for his class, so I remember. What should I do now?

Comment: I think if any homework solution resembles the solution here, something bad may happen.

Comment: Im sorry Mai, im not sure what you are saying?

Comment: @Mai: it's good that you know that there is this discussion going on here, so that you can compare with students' work to see whether there is any possibility of plagiarism. OP (Original Poster): what is the equation of a circle centered at (0,y) with radius 1?

Comment: (x-0)^2 + (y-y)^2 = r^2 ?

Comment: oh it should be = 1 ^

Comment: i looked throught the instructions again and found something related to what you are asking. so should the condition look something like this?: d=(x-distance)^2 + (y-0)^2 if d<1 then its in the circle. this isnt right but i think im closer. this only applied to on circle. can i make a second condition that is similar and make it so that the dart only hits if both are true?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have two unit circles centered at `(distance, 0)` and `(-distance, 0)` (that is, one is slightly to the right of the origin and one is slightly to the left). You're trying to determine if a given point, `(x, y)` is within both circles.

The simplest approach might be to simply compute the distance between the point and the center of each of the circles. You've already done this in your previous code, just repeat the computation twice, once with the offset distance inverted, then use `and` to see if your point is in both circles.

But a more elegant solution would be to notice how your two circles intersect each other exactly on the `y`-axis. To the right of the axis, the left circle is completely contained within the right one. To the left of the `y`-axis, the right circle is entirely within the left circle. And since the shape is symmetrical, the two halves are of exactly equal size.

This means you can limit your darts to only hitting on one side of the axis, and then get away with just a single distance test:

```
def circle_intersection_area(num_darts, distance):
    if distance >= 1:
        return 0

    in_circle = 0
    width = 1-distance   # this is enough to cover half of the target

    for i in range(num_darts):
        x = random.random()*width    # random value from 0 to 1-distance
        y = random.random()*2 - 1    # random value from -1 to 1
        d = math.sqrt((x+distance)**2 + y**2)  # distance from (-distance, 0)
        if d <= 1:
            in_circle += 1

    sample_area = width * 2
    target_area = sample_area * (in_circle / num_darts)

    return target_area * 2 # double, since we were only testing half the target
```